# Android turn off push notifications in app preferences screen

Tags: android, push-notification, settings, parse-platform

I want to turn off/on push notification in my app. I am using parse api for push notification. How can I do this issue in my settings screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just unregister push receiver when you dont want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://parse.com/questions/disable-push-notification-service

Look at the this link. Your question's answer is there